# What can give me near-infinite storage?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-feed-the-beast

I have a lot of things. I need a place to store them all.

Barrels store only one thing, but a lot of that one thing.
Applied Energetics systems store 63 types of things per drive.
Chests, are well, chests. The best is the diamond one.

**I am a greedy person and want a way to store *all* my things without taking too much space.** What do I do? I am using the Ultimate pack in Feed The Beast.

Comment: Obviously a puddle of lava.  You can throw an unlimited number of items into it, and it only takes up a 1x1x1 space.  Good luck getting anything back out, though.

Comment: @MBraedley Hey, he just wanted storage, not retrieval. This would make a good answer. ^_^

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Deep Storage Units](http://ftbwiki.org/Deep_Storage_Unit).

A lot of space is taken by the same thing spanning multiple 'slots' in an ME drive. Cobblestone is the worst offender in my system. A single crafting will net you 4 DSUs, and  putting the 4 biggest volume items in DSUs tripled my space when I got full. They're cheaper than drives, if you have one item that you need to store a LOT of.

For easy management of the contents, I'd recommend an ME network using a [Storage Bus](http://ae-mod.info/ME-Storage-Bus/). If you right-click it with a wrench while sneaking, you can set the Storage Bus to have a higher priority than any ME Storage Drive. The movement is bi-directional, too, so you can extract items using your ME Access!

If you are using an ME Export Bus to move contents to the Deep Storage Unit before hooking it up to your ME Network, take care to attach it to an input face. This can be configured using the DSU GUI. A Storage Bus, however, is able to both deposit and withdraw using an output side.

Comment: In Applied Energistics you can use a [Storage Bus](http://ae-mod.info/ME-Storage-Bus/) to add external storage (eg. barrels with an extra-dimensional upgrade) to offload bulk items. Setting the storage bus to have a higher priority and new instances of the item will be placed in the barrel before the AE drives.

Comment: @Richard Wow, I did not know that. So the Storage Bus can connect to barrels, chests, and DSUs? This solves one of my issues that was in the back of my mind, if so.

Comment: @Coronus: Certainly barrels (Factorization) and chests (Vanilla, Iron Chests, …). Never used MineFactory Reloaded so cannot confirm DSU (but AE supports multiple mod's storage approaches).

Comment: Additional piece of information: storage bus can be assign a priority when sneak-right-clicking it with a wrench. Setting it to the highest of your priorities should ensure the DSU gets to store any of the mats you put into the ME. (You may have to retrieve the ones already on drives though)

Comment: @M'vy During setup, I'd recommend using an ME Export Bus to get large quantities into the DSU before attaching a Storage Bus. That way you can be assured everything gets in there. In fact, if you didn't need immediate access to the contents, the Export Bus could stay on until you got around to swapping it out.

Comment: Also if connected to an ME network then I recommend sub-netting them Super Soaryn Drive style and then you can expand it infinitely and not need to worry about the ME channels it takes, here is my network for it: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/28532909/2015-06-02_20.14.15.png

Answer (score 2):

Immibis' tubestuff mod adds a Black hole chest which can (very nearly, it has up to 2^31 pages) store an infinite amount of items in it so that is definitively the most compact way possible to store (effectively) *all* your things. However the configs disable it by default so you would need to be able to edit them to make it available in survival mode.

It has also been known in previous versions to be quite buggy and easily capable of losing all of your items, I don't know whether this has been fixed. The chest is also not sortable so if you stored all your stuff in it you might never find some of it again.

Other than this your next best option for compact storage is an ME Drive, which can hold up to 10 me storage disks for up to 630 item types in a single block, which has the downside of requiring an ME network to connect to but the associated benefit of being able to hide the storage somewhere else and only having a few access blocks visible in your base.

An alternative approach (and the one I like to take after I've got an initial base setup and enough resources available) is to instead of storing *all* the things *all* the time just store enough of the things for your (optimistic) near-future needs and have an automation setup that will replenish your stocks as you use them. In short slow down your collecting of *all* the things so that you don't need as much storage space at once.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a **Black Hole Chest** which can store indefinitely

Answer (score -1):

Put all of your things on 64k storage disks, then once you've filled a 128^3 area full of drives holding these disks make that a spacial disk, place that in a bag of holding - proceed to fill the bag of holding then put this as the only item on your new 64k storage disk ad nauseam. Pro tip: Helps if you format the disks to only hold bags of holding.